# Can I capture HTTP request from port 8080 on postman?

Tags: http, request, postman, wireshark, capture

I'm capturing all the HTTP requests of 8080 port with wireshark only adding this:

[image]

Can I do this on Postman? I want to capture the trafict of my 8080 port with desktop Postman, is it possible?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `built-in proxy` in the `Postman` native apps or use the `Interceptor extension` for the Postman app. Postman's proxy feature is used to inspect HTTP communication going out from your phone. To get started, make sure your computer and mobile are connected to the same local wireless network.

Refer  Link for detail information : https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/capturing-http-requests/

But I think  `Fiddler Classic` is more user friendly tool and can be used easily to capture all HTTP traffic.

To download the fiddler, Refer link: https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler